# Working with .startswith and is_unique in python to create new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Example:
I have the first three columns and need to create the new order column based on the previous ones. The new order should say no if the order number is repeated. However, it should say yes if the order number is unique or if the item starts with a "WC". The problem is that the two science courses have duplicated order number but since it starts with a WC, the value in new order column should be 'Yes'. I know i should use is_unique and .startswith to do this but i am not sure how to combine these two to get the result.

| Item | Name | Order Number | New Order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Calc | Math | 100 | No |
| Algebra | Math | 100 | No |
| Geometry | Math | 300 | Yes |
| WCChem | Science | 200 | Yes |
| WCBio | Science | 200 | Yes |

Dictionary to construct the DataFrame:

```
dic = {'Item': ['Calc', 'Algebra', 'Geometry', 'WCChem', 'WCBio'],
       'Name': ['Math', 'Math', 'Math', 'Science', 'Science'],
       'Order Number': [100, 100, 300, 200, 200],
       'New Order': ['No', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes']}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `~duplicated` (with `keep=False` to select all duplicates) to identify non-duplicate values and use `str.startswith` to identify the "Item" values that start with "WC". Now since you want a "Yes" if either of these are True, you use `|` operator and wrap it in a `np.where` to assign "Yes", "No" values:

```
df['New_Order'] = np.where(~df['Order_Number'].duplicated(keep=False) | df['Item'].str.startswith('WC'), 'Yes', 'No')
```

Output:

```
       Item     Name  Order Number New Order
0      Calc     Math           100        No
1   Algebra     Math           100        No
2  Geometry     Math           300       Yes
3    WCChem  Science           200       Yes
4     WCBio  Science           200       Yes
```